# How can i find maximum byte in file?

Tags: java, file-io, byte, fileinputstream

so basicaly i have file C:/test.txt, and output which i get(55) isnt correct, i want to find maximum byte in that file,  can someone please help me to understand what do i do wrong, or is there mistake in my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
            {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
              String filName = bufferedReader.readLine();
                int max;
                FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(filName);

                max = fileReader.read();
                while (fileReader.available() > 0)
                {
                    if (max < fileReader.read())
                    {
                        max = fileReader.read();
                    }
                }
                fileReader.close();
                System.out.println(max);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Java?  C#?  Visual Basic?  Add one to your tags.

Comment: And maybe a sample of that data or correct result? My crystal ball isn't clear today.

Comment: And what is going wrong? The wrong answer, an exception, a compile-time error, hard drive reformatting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you read the byte at position N, and if it's greater than your current max, you replace max with the byte at position N + 1:

```
if (max < fileReader.read())
{
     max = fileReader.read();
}
```

Can you see how this won't work? You need to save the result of `fileReader.read()` so you can compare it then use it:

```
int current = fileReader.read();
if (current > max)
{
    max = current;
}
```

Also, according to this comment:

> data is 1 2 3 4 5

You're expecting to read integers from the file, when in fact you're reading raw byte/character values. If the file is binary, you'll need to read in integer sized chunks. If the file is text, you'll need to parse integers out of it.